# Coin Flips and Hypothesis Tests

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation, hypothesis-testing

Here's a problem I thought of that I don't know how to approach:

You have a fair coin that you keep on flipping. After every flip, you perform a hypothesis test based on all coin flips thus far, with significance level $\alpha$, where your null hypothesis is that the coin is fair and your alternative hypothesis is that the coin is not fair. In terms of $\alpha$, what is the expected number of flips before the first time that you reject the null hypothesis?

Edit based on comment below: For what values of $\alpha$ is the answer to the question above finite? For those values for which it is infinite, what is the probability that the null hypothesis will ever be rejected, in terms of $\alpha$?

Edit 2: My post was edited to say "You believe that you have a fair coin." The coin is in fact fair, and you know that. You do the hypothesis tests anyway. Otherwise the problem is unapproachable because you don't know the probability that any particular toss will come up a certain way.

Comment: If there is a positive probability that you never reject the null hypothesis, then the expectation is infinite. [I don't know whether or not there is such a positive probability.]

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: This answer was unclear for OP at first, so I tried to make it clearer through a new approach. Apparently it arose another legitimate doubt, so I tried now to put both answers together and clarify them even more. *(Still I might be wrong, but I'll try to express myself better)*

What you look for, is the expected number of tosses before we do a *Type I* error (rejecting $H_0$ when it was true). The probability of that is precisely $\alpha$ (that's another way to define it).

So $P(Type\ I\ error)=\alpha$.

Let $X_n$ be the event of rejecting $n^{th}$ test.

Now, $E[X_1]=\alpha$ stands for the expected number of *games* (a game is starting to test in the way we do a new coin) where $H_0$ was rejected on the first throw. $E[X_1+X_2]=E[X_1]+E[X_2]$ is the expected number of games where $H_0$ is rejected either on the first or the second throw. Note that with most $\alpha$ this will be lower than $1$, so the expectation for a single game is not to reject $H_0$ yet.

When do we expect to have rejected $H_0$? Precisely when the number of expected games in which we reject $H_0$ is $1$. Therefore, we look for $n$ such as
$$
E[X_1+X_2+...+X_n]=1\\
E[X_1+X_2+...+X_n]=E[nX_1]=nE[X_1]=n\alpha=1\\ n=\frac{1}{\alpha}
$$

---

The other answer goes like this: Let the variable $T$ count the number of tests before rejecting one. We look for $E[T]$.

Also, using previous notation, $P(X_n)=\alpha(1-\alpha)^{n-1}$ (I'm aware this implies independence between the events $X_n$ and $X_{n-1}$ but since I'm looking for the expected value, for the [linearity of the Expected Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Properties), it shouldn't be a problem, though I'm aware I'm not being polite with notation).

$$E[T] = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nP(X_n) =
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\alpha(1-\alpha)^{n-1}=
\alpha\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(1-\alpha)^{n-1}=\\
\alpha\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)(1-\alpha)^{n}=
\alpha(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(1-\alpha)^{n}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(1-\alpha)^{n}) =
\alpha(\frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha^2}+\frac{1}{\alpha}) \\
E[T]=\frac{1}{\alpha}
$$

Comment: Can you explain why we are looking for $n$ such that $E[X_1 + X_2 + \dots + X_n] = 1$?

Comment: I look for when the expected number of rejected $H_0$ is 1.

Comment: Why is this the same as the expected number of flips before the null hypothesis is rejected for the first time?

Comment: It's what you asked. The expected number of flips until a hypothesis test rejects $H_0$, when doing one after each flip. I don't get your doubt, please be more specific about what you don't understand of the reasoning.

Comment: You showed that $\frac{1}{\alpha}$ is the value of $n$ such that the expected number of rejections for the first $n$ tests is equal to $1$. I am asking for the expected number of tests before the first rejection. I may be missing something, but I don't see why those two should be the same.

Comment: You were right. I was messing up some concepts I'm afraid. This seems like it should be the right answer. I'm sorry for all the problems, but I use to answer these questions at work and sometimes I don't have all the time I'd like to analyze them.

Comment: Thanks. I think in your calculations you left out a plus sign (so when you split into two sums, shouldn't you add them instead of multiplying them?) But I think my bigger issue is with $P(X_n) = \alpha(1 - \alpha)^{n - 1}$. This makes sense if you assume that the probabilities of rejecting the null hypotheses are independent of one another. But I don't think this is the case: the fact that you haven't rejected the first few null hypotheses I think decreases the probability that you will reject the next one to a value that is (significantly) below $\alpha$.

Comment: Well, sorry for the mistake. I'm aware of what you said but since you ask for expected value it shouldn't matter. It coincides also with my other calculations. Take into account what I did the other way. The thing is that you can use the independence of the expected value property.

Comment: I'm still not convinced by the rigor of either approach. Linearity of expectations says you can add expected values even if they're not linearly independent, but I don't think that that's what you're doing here. (Here you're using the formula $P(A \text{ and } B) = P(A)P(B)$, which is only true when $A$ and $B$ are independent events.